# MALFORMED_QUERY: ;Id > '0X8000000000000' ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 249999

Tags: soql, einstein-analytics, sync, event-monitoring

I am trying to synch the ListViewEvent object to Einstein Analytics, but when I do I get the following error [image: EA error]

I am selecting, only few fields, so I don't understand why my sync object isn't working, is it related to this object in particular?

Full error code is the following :

```
Something went wrong while executing the Sync_ListViewEvent node: MALFORMED_QUERY: ;Id > '0X8000000000000' ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 249999; ^;ERROR at Row:1:Column:68;field 'Id' can not be sorted in a query call (02K070000004fcdEAA_03C070000000uV0EAI)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Event Monitoring Big Objects are not yet supported in Einstein Analytics (although I think a few of the older ones like API might work)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_objects_monitoring.htm

Comment: Yes, that's what I was told by the support after opening a Case. ListViewEvent and ReportEvent objects are not supported yet by EA. Other objects like APIEvent, LoginEvent are already useable in EA.

Answer (score 0):

I see from the error message that the query you are forming is sorting(Order BY) based on the Id field which is not allowed.

Also, I see your query has where ID greater than (ID>) even comparing Ids is also invalid.

You need to fix both of these in your query.

Comment: I am not executing any query, this message pops when I sync the object ListViewEvent from Salesforce to Einstein Analytics

Comment: If this is Salesforce formed query then mostly it should be a bug on them. You can get a case opened with them for this issue.